# A problem with correct filling for ListPlot and InterpolationOrder 0

Tags: plotting, filling

Using ListPlot I can generate with

```
ListPlot[{{344.41, 272.2, 280}, {345, 223, 278}}, InterpolationOrder -> 0, PlotRange -> {200, 400}, Joined -> True]
```

a simple Plot.

[image: simple plot]

However, if I now use a the "Filling" option Mathematica (12.1)  displays the following wrong result.

```
ListPlot[{{344.41, 272.2, 280}, {345, 223, 278}}, InterpolationOrder -> 0, PlotRange -> {200, 400}, Joined -> True, Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, {Blue}}} ]
```

[image: wrong filling]

As far as I get it, the problem might arrise from the decimals. Is there a known solution for that?

Comment: I think this is a bug.  You should report it to WRI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two work-arounds:

**1.** Use `ListPlot` without the filling option and post-process the output to add the filling polygons as `Epilog`:

```
lp = ListPlot[{{344.41, 272.2, 280}, {345, 223, 278}}, 
  InterpolationOrder -> 0, PlotRange -> {200, 400}, Joined -> True]; 

Show[lp, 
  Epilog -> {Opacity[.5, LightBlue], 
    Polygon @ Join[#, Reverse @ #2] & @@ Cases[lp, Line[x_, ___] :> x, All]}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, use `FilledCurve` instead of `Polygon`:

```
Show[lp, 
   Epilog -> {Opacity[.5, LightBlue], 
      FilledCurve @ ({#, Reverse /@ #2} & @@ Cases[lp, _Line, All])}]
```

[image]

**2.** `Rationalize`ing input data for *some* choice of the second argument also works:

```
ListPlot[Rationalize[{{344.41, 272.2, 280}, {345, 223, 278}}, 10^-2], 
 InterpolationOrder -> 0, PlotRange -> {200, 400}, Joined -> True, 
 Filling -> {1 -> {2}}]
```

[image]

***Caveat:*** Need to automate the second argument of `Rationalize` based on input data.

Comment: Interesting: if I use Rationalize[{{344.41, 272.2, 280}, {345, 223, 278}}, 10^-3] => at a higher order the problem is still there.

Comment: @StF, updated with caveats re the `Rationalize` approach.